# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Arts & Crafts has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and your first elected moderators are:

[image: fixer1234]

[image: Joachim]

[image: Elmy]

You can see them listed on [the moderators page](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) - please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the remaining pro-tem team that opted to step down as moderators:

[image: Lyssagal]

[image: Erica]

On a personal note, Erica and I were two of the original three mods appointed here almost six years ago and, while I'm sorry to see her stepping down, I appreciate her being here for so long.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6536597060190208).

Answer (score 3):

**Congratulations, Joachim, fixer1234, and Elmy!**

Joachim, you've already served this site for a long time, nearly 2 years as moderator and before that for even longer as a regular and active user doing a lot of community moderation. Now you're no longer a "pro tem" mod, you're secure in this position for as long as you want. fixer1234 and Elmy, you've provided some of the best quality answers on the site, and nobody could deserve the mod role more. I hope you all continue with the amazing work you're doing here, and help this site to shine.

**Thanks, Erica and Lyssagal!**

Erica, you've been here since the beginning. Six years as a mod is a long time, and for some of that time you served as the *only* A&C mod, after Catija got hired and CreationEdge quit. Thank you for holding up your end so long, and please enjoy a well-deserved rest. Lyssagal, you stood up to take a mod position when almost nobody else would. Thank you for all you've done during the last two years as a moderator, and sorry to see you not continue in the role.

**Thanks and commiserations, Ken Graham!**

This is the second time you've run in an A&C election and come last, but you still played a vital role: without you, there would have been no election both times. Thank you for stepping up to take on the role, even if you didn't win it - for being willing to serve as moderator, and for helping to make the elections competitive.